# Display object (selected from list) in option pane

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist, joptionpane

I write a code in Java for `JList` class that display the selected items from the list using `JOptionPane`, but it does not work correctly. The displaying is in the attached picture.

Can anyone help me?

[screenshot][1]

[image]

Comment: What we are seeing in the option pane is the normal string representation of an array (a `String[]`). It will be necessary to format the selected strings in a suitable string for display.  Change `+(places.getSelectedValues())` to `+(Arrays.toString(places.getSelectedValues()))` & report the new output.

Comment: Stop sabotaging the question content!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
add(l);
```

by:

```
getContentPane().add(l);
```

Do the same for all "add" calls.

Also, "places.getSelectedValues()" returns a Collection. You should iterate on it.

Comment: Why replace all of the "add" calls?  As a convenience add and its variants, (plus remove and setLayout) have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary.

Comment: "have been overridden" in recent JDKs "for convenience" doesn't make it right. If you compile using a not-so-recent JDK, it will not work. It is true that this is not the source of the problem, but I think it was worth mentioning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
places.getSelectedValues();
```

The method returns an Array to you see the toString representation of the Array.

If you read the API for the `getSelectedValues()` method you will see that it is deprecated. Don't ignore warning messages when you compile your classes!!!

The API suggests you use the `getSelectedValuesList()` method. This method return a list which will format the items in the list for you.

If you don't like the default formatting of the List then you will need to iterate through the list and format the text yourself.